# 401 (Unauthorized) WebResource.axd

Tags: asp.net, security, webforms, devexpress

I have a website that is secured with windows authentication and role provider, however the site also has a public section that allows access by anyone.

```
<location path="Public">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
        <allow users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

The public page is a data entry page with some DevExpress Controls with required field validation etc.

The page is trying to access WebResource.axd and is failing with this error: **Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)**

How can I grant access to WebResource.axd from the public pages while maintaining the permissions on the rest of the site?

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this.

```
   <location path="path for your axd file">
      <system.web>    
         <authorization>
            <allow users="?" />
         </authorization>
      </system.web>
   </location>
```

Comment: The WebResource.axd is defined in the machine's web.config <add path="WebResource.axd" verb="GET" type="System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader" validate="True" />. I am not sure if this suggestion will work?